# Deploying with capistrano and 'Host key verification failed.' promble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, ssh, capistrano, linode

I'm trying to setup my Rails app on Linode and I'm at the stage of trying to get Capistrano setup.

I have a git server setup on the same server as where I'm deploying. I have my SSH keys setup (I think) -- at least I can SSH in no problem.

Both 'cap deploy:setup' and 'cap deploy:check' run without error.

But then when I try to run 'cap deploy:migrations' I get the following:

```
ray@ray-ThinkPad-SL:~/mini-saler$ cap deploy:migrations
  * executing `deploy:migrations'
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@XX.207.243.215:mini-saler.git master"
    command finished in 12446ms
  * executing "if [ -d /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags  origin && git reset  --hard 8e8aa8f849a9438851a3767b338ab711d6470299 && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone git@XX.207.243.215:mini-saler.git /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -b deploy 8e8aa8f849a9438851a3767b338ab711d6470299; fi"
    servers: ["XX.207.243.215"]
    [XX.207.243.215] executing command
 ** [XX.207.243.215 :: out] Cloning into /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy...
 ** [XX.207.243.215 :: err] Host key verification failed.
 ** [XX.207.243.215 :: err] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 2009ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'if [ -d /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git fetch --tags  origin && git reset  --hard 8e8aa8f849a9438851a3767b338ab711d6470299 && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone git@XX.207.243.215:mini-saler.git /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/railsu/bianbian.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -b deploy 8e8aa8f849a9438851a3767b338ab711d6470299; fi'" on XX.207.243.215
```

deploy.rb

```
set :user, 'railsu'
set :domain, 'XX.207.243.215'
set :application, 'mini-saler'
# adjust if you are using RVM, remove if you are not
$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))
require "rvm/capistrano"
set :rvm_ruby_string, '1.9.3'
set :rvm_type, :user
# file paths
set :repository, "git@#{domain}:mini-saler.git"
set :deploy_to, "/home/railsu/bianbian.com"
# distribute your applications across servers (the instructions below put them
# all on the same server, defined above as 'domain', adjust as necessary)
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true


# miscellaneous options
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :scm, 'git'
set :branch, 'master'
set :scm_verbose, true
set :use_sudo, false
set :rails_env, :production

namespace :deploy do
  desc "cause Passenger to initiate a restart"
  task :restart do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end
  desc "reload the database with seed data"
  task :seed do
    run "cd #{current_path}; rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}"
  end
end

after "deploy:update_code", :bundle_install
desc "install the necessary prerequisites"
task :bundle_install, :roles => :app do
  run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install"
end
```

I can use ssh to connect my vps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall if any git commands are called on `cap deploy:setup` or `cap deploy:check` - I don't think there are.

Assuming you're using gitolite, check to make sure that your configuration has your `railsu` user's public key is in the `keydir` directory.

Or perhaps agent forwarding is what you want?  [Deploying with Capistrano](https://help.github.com/articles/deploying-with-capistrano) can help you there.